# Should we call base method if override it in descendant?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, solid-principles

I've hear several times not calling a base method in overriden method of a descendant class is an anti pattern. Could any one please explain whether this is true? If yes, then I would like to know whether it is always true.

Comment: Unless your base method implementation needed in your overridden method (mat be some common logic across)

Comment: [Call Super](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_super) anti pattern. this block explains it all, I think: "The anti-pattern is the requirement of calling the parent. There are many examples in real code where the method in the subclass may still want the superclass's functionality, usually where it is only augmenting the parent functionality. **If it still has to call the parent class even if it is fully replacing the functionality, the anti-pattern is present.**"

Comment: @OguzOzgul, but if we not doing it, doesn't it mean we violate Liskov substition principle because actual behavior of the descendant class may break the base class behavior?

Comment: If the behavior of the sub class "breaks" the expected base class behavior, yes, it is a violation of Liskov's substitution principle. But how do you define "breaking the base class behavior"? Do you consider change in behavior "breaking"? Let us re-read this part : "If it still has to call the parent class **even if it is fully replacing the functionality**". So the sub class replaces the functionality, does not break anything, and this is what inheritance is for.

Comment: @OguzOzgul, I am interested in this question from the point of view of Liskov principle. I understand your point - functionality replacement is ok. But in this case I guess the overriden method still  has to implement preconditions and postconditions of the base method to not violate the principle ?

Comment: Liskov's: "Don't strengthen pre-conditions" (for which, one of the translations can be; 'do not throw an exception by checking the initialization status of a member of the sub-class), "Don't weaken post-conditions" (again, do not cause a change in the super class' state which would not be caused by the base method) etc. If we obey these rules, we don't violate the principle. But still, let's say the base method changes a private member which we don't have access to. Now this is where the code smell is introduced and the principle violated if the base method is not invoked (in my opinion)

Comment: @OguzOzgul, thanks for your answers. Appreaciate.